Как получить сырое содержимое тела (raw body) post или put запроса в .net minimal api?
Как получить сырое содержимое тела (raw body) post или put запроса в .net minimal API?
Я пробовал так:
app.MapPut($"/{controllerName}", async ([FromBody] BasisTypeDto dto, IRepository repo, HttpRequest request, HttpContext context) => {

    BuilderMinimalApiActionResult<object>.MakeActionResult(Crud.Update(dto, repo, host, DefaultElasticIndex)); }
)
    .AddEndpointFilter(async (efiContext, next) => {

        var s = efiContext.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpBodyControlFeature>();

        s.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
        var reader = new StreamReader(efiContext.HttpContext.Request.Body);

        var rawMessage = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return await next(efiContext);
    })

Но в rawMessage получаю пустую строку, хотя efiContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentLength == 112

Данные из Body были прочитаны и десериализованы в BasisTypeDto dto. В документации (в конце этого раздела) сказано: "The request body isn't buffered by default. After the body is read, it's not rewindable. The stream can't be read multiple times."

Для теста уберите из аргументов [FromBody] BasisTypeDto dto и в rawMessage появится содержимое.

@Alexander Petrov, да, я убрал [FromBody] BasisTypeDto dto и содержимое появилось.

Вот здесь дали ответ ответ на этот вопрос с примером того, как использовать EnableBuffering для многоразового чтения тела запроса:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79189212/how-can-i-get-the-raw-body-content-of-a-post-or-put-request-in-the-net-minimal/79190973#79190973
